# Why log disappears when time step goes to limit

Tags: limits

[image]

Hello I’m newbie of math.

And I couldn’t understand why $\log(1 + \mu\delta t)$ goes to $\mu\delta t$ when time step ($\delta t$) goes to zero above the picture.

Please let me know what reference should I study?

Thanks

Comment: $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ when $x\ll 1$.  Are you familiar with Taylor series?

Comment: You should study a calculus book for this

Comment: Yes but I need to look again my math materials.. Although I studied this, I couldn't find out how this can be used. I need to study as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\log'(1)=1$. In other words,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x+1)}x=1.$$Therefore, if $x$ is very close to $0$, then $\log(x+1)$ behaves as $x$.

Answer (score 0):

By L'hopital we have:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to define the natural logarithm is as an integral:
$$
\log x = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t} \, dt \, .
$$
When the logarithm is seen in this light, it is easy to argue geometrically that $\log (1+x) \approx x$:

[image: Geometric interpretation of logarithm]

The value of $\log(1+x)$ is given by the area of the blue region. An upper bound for this region is given by the rectangle with vertices $(1,0)$, $(1+x,0)$, $(1+x,1)$, and $(1,1)$. This rectangle has a width of $x$ and height of $1$, and hence has an area of $x$. As $x$ approaches $0$, the area of the blue region approaches that of the rectangle. Hence, $\log(1+x) \approx x$, with $x$ always being a slight overestimate for the value of $\log(1+x)$.